# Is there a way to figure out when a user marks email as spam

Tags: email, spam

Let's say i'm building software for email marketing , is there any way to figure out wether the end receiver of an email marked it as spam ?

Comment: No.  It's a one-way ticket out of your server.  You may never know if they receive it, if it's marked spam, etc.

Comment: I hope not, not because I care about your reaction, but because it would imply that spam can confirm live email addresses without having to receive a response.

Comment: Just build it so it sends emails that are already marked as spam. Then you can be sure that it is marked as spam at the receiver's end. :)

Comment: Unless you control the remote host or remote email client, no.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.
The only thing I have in mind is to put an image into the mail, reffering a specific ID to check if the user views the mail. After a while you could then say, the user has marked it as spam or doesn't read it, when nothing comes through the image.

But almost every mail-client disables image-loading for the first time and there are other users who don't view HTML-mails, so they won't load the image.

I hope I have helped you a little

Comment: the thing is one of the companies who's services we use (that shall remain nameless) claims to be able to do that and keep spewing out numbers at us that make no sense and keeps banning our account based on them

Comment: which seems like a bunch of bull to me and i'm contemplating of building our own email solution just so we dont have to deal with them anymore

Comment: I made a minor edit so I could reverse my downvote which was supposed to be an upvote